# Import modules from embedded Python script

Tags: python, python-embedding

*tl;dr How do I import a Python module from an embedded Python script, so that the imported module can use the global variables and functions provided by the host system?*

I am writing a Python script for some system (written presumably in C++). I write the script, put it into a special predefined folder, the system executes it on some events.

As the script grows large and unwieldy, I want to split it into several modules, let's say, `module1.py` and `module2.py`, imported by `main_script.py`, which is loaded and executed by the host system. However, the imported modules cannot use global stuff `main_script.py` can (I assume, the host system adds some global variables, functions, classes etc. while loading `main_script.py`; the modules, however, aren't loaded by the host system directly, so they end up not having all those globals).

So far I've come up with the following - it looks for the globals that are present in the `main_script.py` but not in the modules, and adds them to the modules:

```py
#main_script.py
import module1, module2

for m in [module1, module2]:
    for k, v in globals().items():
        if not hasattr(m, k):
            setattr(m, k, v)
```

It works (at least for my case so far) but doesn't look particularly elegant: I have to list the imported modules twice; if I want to import some sub-modules from the modules, I would have to do the same there; I have to watch out for possible global name clashes, etc.) As the problem doesn't sound too uncommon, I feel like I may be reinventing the square wheel here. Is there a better way to do this?

**UPD.:** Based on [my interpretation of?] suggestions from the answer of @Merlin Katz and a comment from @Sraw, I've modified my scripts as follows. First, added an empty script `core.py`. Then modified `main_script.py`:

```py
#main_script.py
import core
#only inject into the empty 'core' module
for k, v in globals().items():
    if not hasattr(core, k):
        setattr(core, k, v)

#can now import modules that depend on those globals
import module1, module2
```

Then, every module that has to use the injected globals should import `core` and use them from there:

```py
#module1.py
import core
_blah = core.blahblah #a shortcut

core.call_global_function()
my_obj1 = core.blahblah.SomeClassDefinedInBlahblah()
my_obj2 = _blah.SomeClassDefinedInBlahblah() #a bit shorter version of the above
#etc.
```

This looks somewhat cleaner and there's no risk of overwriting some existing global variables. Modules, imported by `module1` and `module2` can also simply `import core` and use the global variables.

**UPD.:** Furthermore, I'm not sure if it's worth it, but instead of keeping an empty `core.py` module, you can create it dynamically:

```py
#main_script.py
import sys
from types import ModuleType
core = ModuleType("core")
sys.modules["core"] = core

#inject into our dynamically created 'core' module
for k, v in globals().items():
    if not hasattr(core, k):
        setattr(core, k, v)

#the modules can still import `core` the same way as before
import module1, module2
```

Comment: Are you trying to introduce the sub-namespace into the main namespace? You can use `from module1 import *` and `from module2 import *`. Although this is not recommended as it may cause name confliction.

Comment: @Sraw, from what I understand, I am trying to do rather the opposite.

Comment: Oh, yes. I understand you are trying to introduce the main namespace into sub-namespaces. It really sounds a little bit strange as it seems that you don't have any control about the "injected global variables" in `main_script.py`? I assume that you should be able to create a separated file containing all global variables and import that file in both the main module and sub-modules.

Comment: @Sraw, a host system (not written in Python) loads `main_script.py`, injects the global variables and executes `main_script.py`. `main_script.py` then imports some modules, but the global variables, which were injected into the `main_script.py`, don't get automatically injected into the imported modules. Where does "a separate file containing all global variables" come in?

Answer (score 2):

This should solve having to list modules twice - you can use the `importlib` library to import modules from variable names

```
>>> import importlib
>>> np = importlib.import_module('numpy')
>>> np.pi
3.141592653589793
```

So from a list it would be

```
import importlib
modules = [importlib.import_module(module_name) for module_name in module_names]
for m in modules:
    ...
```

As for syncing globals, I hate to say it but I think there's no perfect way to do it. I've run into the problem before, and my solution was to put every function or variable I wanted to be available in each module into a separate core.py file that each module imported from. Beyond that I think what you have is the simplest way to do it, if there are other solutions I'd be interested to hear them.

Comment: One good thing about python is that if Main module imports A module and B module, and both A and B modules import from C module, C module will only be run once. So you can have as many modules import the same core module without any redundancy. If that makes any sense.